# Is it possible to get list of scopes from slack token?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to get list of scopes from Slack's oAuth token? I am trying to add/remove scopes from the token based on how my users use my slack integration. If I can find out scopes from the token then i can avoid unnecessarily prompting the user for the same scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can use [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) to check if a token is still valid (e.g. you will get receive `invalid_auth` for a revoked token). However, there is no method to query the list of current scopes for a given token (except for workspace tokens, but I am assuming you are asking for normal tokens workspace tokens are still BETA).

But you can of course make manual tests by calling some API methods to see if a token has the required scopes for it. The API method will tell you if your token is missing any scopes.

Comment: Maybe this answer was correct at the time you wrote it, but it is wrong now – if you pass a valid token to `auth.test` the scopes are returned in the `x-oauth-scopes` response header. At least that's true for bot tokens (`xoxb-`), I haven't tested any other token type. "Workspace tokens" are no longer BETA, they are now a deprecated legacy feature. You said "normal tokens", maybe you were talking about what is now called "legacy tokens"?

Answer (score 4):

Heads up for anyone coming up here in 2020. While it's not well documented, you can definitely get your current token scopes (and thus, knowing if you need a re-install) by using [auth.test](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) and reading the response metadata.

Here's how when using [node-slack-sdk](https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk):

```
  const slack = new SlackWebClient(token);
  const slackResponse = await slack.auth.test();
  console.log(slackResponse.response_metadata.scopes;
```

Documentation:

- https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/wiki/Web-Client-features
- https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth-scopes#working-with-scopes

Good luck :)

Comment: For those not using any SDK, and going to the REST API directly – look at the `x-oauth-scopes` header of the `GET /api/auth.test` response, the scopes are in there.

Comment: Following on from @SimonKissane's comment, this is the easiest place to do that now https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test/test